# How to add markers dynamically in the onClick event using SebmGoogleMaps? - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular

I have tried to make code and I have searched in the documentation and forums on how to add markers dynamically to a google maps in angular 2.

Find SebmGoogleMap and it is very easy to use but does not have much documentation or is incomplete but has a lot of potential.

I have a map with predefined markers (always visible on the map) and a list of different places in a `ul-li`.

What I try is to dynamically add markers when clicking somewhere. And if you click somewhere else, the last marker is refreshed.

I tried to get the current map of my component, but it never gets to the `getNativeMap` function of `GoogleMapsAPIWrapper` (neither in the constructor method or `ngOnInit`). With the map object I could add markers and use the DirectionServices function. But I do not get it. The only thing I have been able to achieve is to initialize the map with predefined markers.

This is my current code:

mapPlaces.component.ts:

```
[...]
import { MapsAPILoader, SebmGoogleMap, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  [...]
  styles: [`
    .sebm-google-map-container {
       height: 600px;
     }
  `],
})

export class MapPlacesComponent implements OnInit {

  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  map: any;
  lat: number = -12.987637;
  lng: number = -19.97152527;
  zoom: number = 13;

  constructor(
    private _mapsAPI: MapsAPILoader,
    private _mapsAPIWrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper,
    af: AngularFire) {
    // Works fine
    this.items = af.database.list('default_markers');

    this._mapsAPIWrapper.getNativeMap().then( (map) => {
      // Never enter here. I try to get the current map object.
      this.map = map;
      console.log('Current map: ', this.map)
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    [...]
  }

  // Function when onClick in <ul>-<li> in my HTML for view some place.
  retriveExtraMarker(latLon){
     //Try to load the GMaps API to make use of direction service but it does not work.
    this._mapsAPI.load().then( () => {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlon,
        map: this.map
      });

      [extra code...]
    } )

  }
}
```

mapPlaces.component.html:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li (click)="retriveExtraMarker(some_latlon)">Place One</li>
    <li (click)="retriveExtraMarker(some_latlon)">Place Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
      <div>
        <!-- I would like to add more markers dinamically here -->
        <sebm-google-map [zoom]="zoom" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
          <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let item of items | async" [latitude]="item.latitude" [longitude]="item.longitude">
          </sebm-google-map-marker>
        </sebm-google-map>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What is the correct way to add markers in angular 2 using SebmGoogleMap? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Did you found a solution? Looks like we are trying to do the same thing : adding markers dynamically from a firebase database.